# How to navigate to another screen in android using onListItemClick

Tags: android, android-layout, listitem

I am kind of new to Android development. Could you please tell me, how to navigate to another screen using `onListItemClick`. I have 200 items in a `ListView`. If i click an item from the `ListView`, it has to navigate to another screen which should show the details of the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are getting the list and detail of actor from database.
I have used the same walk through to display recipe detail of selected recipe in my app.

```
    public class ActorList extends Activity {

       ListView myActorList=null;

public final static String selectedActor_ID="will Keep Actor ID";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_actor_list);     

        //initialize controls

            myActorList.setAdapter(adapter);

            myActorList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent i= new Intent(ActorList.this,ActorDetail.class);
                    // you have to pass the actor id to next activity
                    // you can get this actor id from argument of type "long"
                    i.putExtra(selectedActor_ID, String.valueOf(id));
                    startActivity(i);

                }           

            });

    }



}


//Other Activity To show Detail..

//get the ID of Selected Actor on other activity say "ActorDetail"

public class ActorDetail extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_actor_detail);

        ActorID=getIntent().getStringExtra(ActorList.selectedActor_ID);
// now as you have the id here for that particular actor
//fetch the detail of that selected actor thru id and bind it to your layout.       


    }



}
```

You need to register the other activity in Manifest file also like this

```
<activity 
            android:name=".otherscreenActivity" 

        </activity>
```

Comment: yes exactly what i mean....

OR You can use "ExpandableListView" so as to display details as child

Comment: @Joel Sorry.Still i am not able to understand.And i am getting an error also..What i wannna do is "I have a list of actors.For example if i click Tom hanks ,it has to navigate to another screen which should show his details.

Comment: My code :
public class ActorsListActivity extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_actors_list);
String[] items=new String[] {"Tom hanks","Leonardo D","Clint eastwood"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.actors_row,R.id.text1,items);
  
  setListAdapter(adapter);
 }

Comment: I dont think so you need to extend ListActivity in you Case extending Activity will work even...

Look at my updated answer I had done that thru database...

You need to preserve Index of array (so as to get details of which actor u need to show on next activity)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you can do something like this...

1>create another activity with certains controls in which you can place your values...

2>on itemclick() of listview...
    a>create intent and set values to pass to new activity
    b>start new activity with this intent.

3>in oncreate() of new activity
    a>retrive the values from intent
    b>populate your controls using the values...